# How do you compare generic types in Swift?

Tags: swift

I am new to Swift development. I have experience in Java before and I am trying to compare two generic types. In java this can be done with ==, but when I tried to do the same I got "Binary Operator '==' cannot be applied to two 'T' operand"

My code is this:

```
    func contains(value: T) -> Bool {
    var current = head
    for _ in 1...count {
        if (current.item! == value) {
            return true
        }
        current = current.next!
    }
    return false
```

It's a method of a linkedlist. I tried making the method header to, but it still does not work.

```
func contains<T: Equatable>(value: T) ->
```

I am new to Swift so can someone please help explain how I can fix this error?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To help us help you, please a minimum working example to demonstrate your problem: [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What type is `current.item`?

Comment: Is your `LinkedList` class generics? If so, you can constraint `T` to implement `Equatable`.

Answer (score -1):

Please find compilable code in Swift 4

```
func contains<T: Equatable>(value1: T, value2: T){
if value1 == value2{
    print("Equal")
}
}

contains(value1: 1, value2: 1)

func newContains<T: Comparable>(value1: T, value2: T){
if value1 == value2{
    print("Equal")
}else if value1 > value2{
    print("Greater than")
}
}

newContains(value1: 2, value2: 1)
```

How this works?

As we know, conforming to a protocol means implementing all the required methods in that protocol. Comparable protocol has got all the comparison methods as required parameters, and any type that is implementing Comparable will be able to do a comparison.

Answer (score -2):

you can cast the type

```
 as? (typeHere)
```

OR

```
 typeHere(value)
```

I might try creating a variable and cast the type like

```
var bob : typeHere?
```

then use

```
bob = value
```

kind of hard to help tho, just my two cents